what is the solution to the failure to change the channel in the flutter?
this problem occurs when i try to change the channel in flutter :
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3880]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\almas>flutter channel
Flutter channels:
master (latest development branch, for contributors)
main (latest development branch, follows master channel)
beta (updated monthly, recommended for experienced users)
stable (updated quarterly, for new users and for production app releases)

[user-branch]

Currently not on an official channel.
C:\Users\almas>flutter channel
Flutter channels:
master (latest development branch, for contributors)
main (latest development branch, follows master channel)
beta (updated monthly, recommended for experienced users)
stable (updated quarterly, for new users and for production app releases)

[user-branch]

Currently not on an official channel.
change the channel to famous channel

I don't understand the text you pasted.  Are you typing "flutter channel stable"?
